# How to use three unrelated views in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement a dictionary app on ASP.NET MVC5 with EF. These are the three models :

Word :

```
public int WordID { get; set; }
public int WordNumber { get; set; }
public string  WordText { get; set; }
```

Meaning :

```
public int MeaningID { get; set; }
public int WordNumber { get; set; }
public int MeaningNumber { get; set; }
public string  MeaningText { get; set; }
```

Example:

```
public int ExampleID { get; set; }
public int WordNumber { get; set; }
public int MeaningNumber { get; set; }
public int ExampleNumber { get; set; }
public string  ExampleText { get; set; }
```

There shouldn't be any foreign keys in these tables. What I want to do is, when I find a word I should find and display all meanings related to that word and all examples related to correct meaning. I can find all related meanings and examples. But I am unable to display them on a view. I opened a view about **word**, it displays words, but I don't know how to display other data on this view or any other view. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a viewmodel that contains all three and then use that to display

Comment: Show your views. Also *“There shouldn't be any foreign keys in these tables”* is a complete nonsense. There *are* foreign keys in your data structures. Otherwise there wouldn't be a way to pair meanings with words and examples. `WordNumber`, `MeaningNumber`, and `ExampleNumber` smell exactly like foreign keys.

Comment: @3dd I thought about it. But how I should handle the relationship between meaning and example in those viewmodels?

Comment: @OndrejTucny There is an existing database which contains no relation in these tables. It was implemented like that years ago and it's pretty big. So I guess I can't change it.

Comment: In the controler when creating the viewmodel, fill in the correct sections according to the users input, I'm sure you'll need to query your db to find the related entities, or setup the relationships in the viewmodel and handle it in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `ViewModel` for `Word` class like below:

```
public class WordViewModel
{
    public Word Word { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Meaning> WordMeanings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Example> WordExamples { get; set; }  
}
```

With user input for word, in your controller action method, you can load the data into the viewModel and send viewModel object back to the view.

You can design your view as you want (load all data at once, load data on demand, etc). But the approach would remain same i.e. load data related to word into a viewModel object.

Comment: +1. Also following this method you could pass the WordMeaning and WordExamples models into their own respective PartialViews.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question : Is it completely safe to use List<T> instead of IENumerable<T>?

Comment: @jason - "Completely safe", well yes..... But as you are not intended to make changes when you pass collection data to view, IEnumerable is well suited. There are other diff when you use List vs IEnumerable.

Comment: I want to use List because I want to add data in a loop in WordExamples for example. I think List is better for that purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to take three classes to the view. you have many options to achieve your goal.

You can use tuple class to concatenate all three classes in view.

```
Word objWord = new Word(); //Your object;

Meaning objMeaning = new Meaning();

Example objExample = new Example();

var tupleModel = new Tuple<Word, Meaning, Example>(objWord, objMeaning, objExample);
return View(tupleModel);
```

In your view you have to add below line on top

```
@model Tuple<Word, Meaning, Example>
```